# Using FindRoot on a function defined with FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving

Simplified starting point: I have a function of two variables

```
f[a_, x_] := x^2 + a^2 - 4;
```

and define a function that gives an `x` depending on `a` for which the equation `f[a,x]==0` holds:

```
xsol[a_] := x /. FindRoot[f[a, x], {x, 1}];
```

Now I'd like to find an `a` for which `xsol[a]` has a specific value (e.g. xsol[a]==1). As I can't call `xsol[a]` symbolically, the following produces the `FindRoot::nlnum` error:

```
asol = a /. FindRoot[xsol[a] == 1, {a, 1}]
```

yet, for some reason (in this case), still gives a correct solution.

How can i find `asol` without receiving this error?

This example might seem somewhat stupid, as one could set `x=1` in the Definition of `f[x,a]` and find `asol`. My actual problem involves three more complicated eqations and 4 variables, and the final `FindRoot`-call is supposed to determine whether another function of these variables can have some specific value (and thus you can't extract information from that last condition to simplify the problem, as in this example).

**Note:** One of my equations is transcendental. Therefore, as far as I understand, `FindRoot` is best used, and some built-in algorithms for equation solving won't work.

Comment: Look at the result of `Plot[xsol[a], {a, -4, 4}]` to understand possible difficulties.

Comment: Already did. I'd say as long as |a|<2 and 0 < x <= 2 there is nothing to worry about...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `xsol` is being passed a symbolic value (`a`), and the `FindRoot` in the definition is then complaining about being passed a symbolic value.  You can avoid the error message by redefining `xsol` so that it does not evaluate unless it is passed a numeric value:

```
xsol[a_?NumericQ] := x /. FindRoot[f[a, x], {x, 1}];

{ xsol[a], xsol[1.5] }

(* xsol[a], 1.32288 *)
```

Calling `asol` with this `xsol` definition still returns an warning about the step size getting too small, but the  `FindRoot::nlnum` error is eliminated.

You didn't ask, but in case you're curious:  The step-size warning might be eliminated by increasing `WorkingPrecision`.  You could also try using `Method -> "Brent"`, which is a bracketing algorithm rather than a secant method.  For that algorithm, you will need to provide two values for `a` in the second argument of `FindRoot` which are known to bracket a root;  depending on the nature of your actual problem, this may or may not be feasible.

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem. Out of even more curiosity: How would i make e.g. `Maximize` work, to find the maximum of `xsol[a]`? `Maximize[xsol[a], a]` threw the same error beforehand, now with `?NumericQ` in the function definition just ouputs the input.

Comment: @wunschwaschbaer:  I think you want `NMaximize` or `FindMaximum`.  `Maximize` is designed for symbolic inputs, not numeric.  Beyond that, these two functions have a host of options that you can tweak to try to get better behavior.  See the guides [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html) and [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html), and be prepared to get lost in the weeds.

Comment: Agh, that was a somwhat obvious mistake. Thank you!